# How to find set point for PID controller for self balancing robot?

Tags: gravity, gyroscopes

I am building a Self balancing robot and needs to tune PID controller to generate PWM signals.

My robot chassis is home made and not in perfect alignment. I have placed 6 axis motion sensor on top of the robot assembly. But due to irregularity in chassis, I assume that set point is not 0 degree horizontal.

I believe that I have to find center of gravity of my robot and align my senor with that line.

How to determine the set point in this case?

Here is assembly of my robot. The blue thing on top is sensor.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps hold it upside-down by the wheels and make note of the reading at this point. Then use some math to rotate 180 degrees. It sounds childishly simple but it might work for your issue.

Comment: This might be a better friend of Engineering Stack Exchange.

Comment: just do brute force method to determine the center point value for the motion sensor. make sure you turn off I and D components first...